# values are not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

```
<?php
  $ll=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `colum` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ord` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tex` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `search` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `count` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `order` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;INSERT INTO p (title,colum,ord,tex,search,count,order) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$f','$h','$g');") or die(mysql_error())  ;
if($ll){
 echo  "insert AND CREATE ";}
 else {echo "fail"; }
?>
```

I am working in a php language . In this page if the table is not created 1st create it and then insert the values into the column

After  creating the table , I am inserting the values into the table but it showing me the error in the insert query

I am getting a this error- **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO p VALUES ('count','name','asc','1','search','count','order ')' at line 11**

what am i doing wrong

Comment: And what did you tried? Why do not simply do the standard debug?

Comment: Have you tried the sql in, for example, Phpmyadmin?

Comment: The #1 thing you're doing wrong is using the deprecated mysql_ functions. As for the error, I don't think you can execute two queries at the same time.

Comment: @KeesSonnema yes dear , i have tried it and its working but when i use this in my code . it shows me the error

Comment: Try by given the space before the insert or try to execute the insert query separately.

Comment: @Juhana i have tried this sql in phpmyadmin also and its working

Comment: Again, **you can't execute the two queries at the same time**. Make a separate `mysql_query()` call for the insert.

Comment: @Juhana my situation is like this ............ (1) my first page is a form which collects the 7 values and when a user click on the button its checks whether the table is created or not ......if created then insert the values and if not created the it comes to this query

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. You can't have two queries inside `mysql_query()` no matter what your situation is.

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday... and i think you got an answer ... @Juhana is right by the way  ...

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `colum` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ord` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tex` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `search` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `count` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `order` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;INSERT INTO p (title,colum,ord,tex,search,count,order) VALUES ('a','b','c','d','f','$h','g');

Comment: if you use the above query in phpmyadmin , it will create the table and insert the value . so why the query is not running in php

Comment: -1 You have edited your SQL statement but not the error message

Comment: FWIW you have a **HUGE** SQL injection security hole in your code assuming any of your variables come from user input

Comment: Jesus christ on a pogo stick. It doesn't work in PHP because ***you can't execute two queries at the same time with `mysql_query()`.***

Comment: Please choose a correkt answer to give someone some credit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO p (title,colum,ord,tex,search,count,order) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$f','$h','$g')
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO p (`title`,`colum`,`ord`,`tex`,`search`,`count`,`order`) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$f','$h','$g')
```

Hence **order** is a mysql keyword

Answer (score 1):

I am not absolutly sure if that is the problem but you are passing 7 values in your INSERT statement while your table deffinition has 8 fields.

I assume you are doing that because 'id' field is autoincremental. However, if that is the case, you should specify which columns correspond with your values in the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO $p (title, column, ord, ...) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$f','$h','$g')
```

Comment: @user2657625 Why don't you try to print your SQL sentence on your screen so you can run it using a MySQL client or at least copy it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dry run seperating the two statements - should work:

```
<?php
$querys[]="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $p (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `colum` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `ord` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `tex` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `search` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `count` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `order` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

$querys[]="INSERT INTO $p VALUES (null,'$a','{$b}','{$c}','{$d}','{$f}','{$h}','{$g}')";


foreach($querys as $sql) {
    $ll = mysql_query($sql);
    $error=mysql_error();
    if($error!='') {
        print $sql."\n";
        die($error);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

you have ended the insert statement with a " double quote but not started you can write either

```
INSERT INTO p (title,colum,ord,tex,search,count,order) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$f','$h','$g');
```

or you can write

```
("INSERT INTO p (title,colum,ord,tex,search,count,order) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$f','$h','$g')");
```

try it in your code

note - please do not use mysqli and mysql in same code, rather you can use mysqli PDO

Comment: The `"` is up earlier in the string. In any case a missing PHP string delimiter wouldn't give a MySQL error.